# The fastest way to fill test data to cassandra unit?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, cassandra, bulk-load, bigdata

I'm using cassandra unit for testing in my project (Java) and it's great but the problem is:loading test data takes quite a long time (100 secs for ~25 000 plain inserts).

I have some ideas but they don't seem to be feasible for cassandra unit:

- use something like cqlsh command COPY FROM to copy data from csv
- backup prepared data folder and give it to CU at initialization.

Do you have other ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Depends a bit if mentioned data is modified, but e.g. you can have a standalone instance with this data to be read by those tests. You may also check how batches would work with cassandra unit, just remeber batches in cluster environment are not appropriate for multi partion inserts.

Answer (score 1):

The way to load up a lot of data all at once is to use the [unlogged batch mechanism](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html):

```
BEGIN UNLOGGED BATCH
INSERT INTO ...;
INSERT INTO ...;
INSERT INTO ...;
...
APPLY BATCH;
```

It may not be fast, but for test purposes it should not be a problem and you should avoid timeouts that a straight set of INSERT will likely generate (because you fill up the log file and Cassandra stops accepting data for a while after that.)

Comment: Such approach gives me an error:  
mismatched input ';' expecting K_APPLY  
Removed ';' after 'UNLOGGED BATCH' then error is:  
mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting K_APPLY

Comment: Sorry, I should not have put the `;` after the `BATCH` keyword. Also, the `...` just means add other `INSERT` as required, so I would imagine you did not put that in your list of instructions. The link gives you additional documentation (there are more features available with `BATCH`. Also this should work with Cassandra 2.0 and over.